# Is ISIS committing genocide against the Yazidis?

Tags: united-states, politics, isis

From [Fact Checks of the Eighth Republican Debate](http://nyti.ms/1RoSFGE), on the New York Times website:

> Senator Marco Rubio said President Obama had played down the threat of
>   the Islamic State, which practices genocide.
>
> **An exaggeration.**
>
> Senator Marco Rubio's charge that President Obama has played down the
>   threat of the Islamic State ends up inflating the threat from the
>   group. While it is true that the Islamic State has targeted Christians
>   and Yazidis, there is no evidence that it has carried out genocide
>   against those groups.
>
> — Mark Landler

I was under the impression that no-one's disputing that ISIS is taking Yazidis as sex slaves and forcibly converting them to Islam, which easily qualifies as genocide. The only thing I don't know about is whether ISIS is systematically killing Yazidis and/or a subset of Yazidis (what some people may refer to with genocide).

The New York Times has [form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_York_Times#World_War_II) for failing to state that a genocide is going on.

Is there no evidence that ISIS has committed genocide against the Yazidis?

**Update** The New York Times has since issued a correction and updated its statement:

> Senator Marco Rubio said President Obama had played down the threat of the Islamic State, which practices "genocide against Christians and Yazidis and others in the region."
>
> **An exaggeration**.
>
> Senator Marco Rubio's charge that President Obama has played down the
>   threat of the Islamic State ends up inflating the threat from the
>   group. Several organizations have concluded that the Islamic State
>   targeted Yazidis with a campaign of genocide, but there is no evidence
>   that it so targeted Christians.
>
> Correction: An earlier version of this fact check imprecisely
>   described the Islamic State's record of treatment of religious
>   minorities in areas where it has operated. Several organizations have
>   concluded there is evidence the group carried out a campaign of
>   genocide against the Yazidis, as Mr. Rubio asserted; it was not
>   accurate to say that there is no evidence to support that claim. The
>   statement was made in a Republican presidential debate in January, and
>   the matter was recently brought to The New York Times's attention by
>   several readers.
>
> — Mark Landler

Comment: There's a lot of controversy and confusion about when to use the word "genocide" - here's an interesting [article from GenocideWatch](http://www.genocidewatch.org/usingwordgenocide.html) about some of the common reasons media outlets are reluctant to use the term, which they argue stem largely from misunderstandings of the UN Convention. It's about Darfur but the principles are similar and it's very useful context.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Yazidis_by_ISIL) has 140 sources.

Comment: ISIS has been decimated and aren't really in a position to commit genocide against anybody.  Maybe this question is better asked in the past tense?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At least 5,000 Yazidi civilians have been murdered.

Quoting from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Yazidis_by_ISIL) article:

> **Classification as Genocide**
>
> The persecution of the Yazidi people has been viewed as qualifying as
>   genocide by groups such as the Office of the United Nations High
>   Commissioner for Human Rights in a March 2015 report. The organization
>   cited the numerous atrocities such as forced religious conversion and
>   sexual slavery as being parts of an overall malicious
>   campaign.[[10]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Yazidis_by_ISIL#cite_note-BBCRussian-10)[[98]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Yazidis_by_ISIL#cite_note-98) Multiple individual human rights
>   activists such as Nazand Begikhani and Dr. Widad Akrawihave also
>   advocated for this view.[[51]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Yazidis_by_ISIL#cite_note-widad.org-51)[[99]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Yazidis_by_ISIL#cite_note-99) The term itself first
>   arose in 1944 as the creation of a Polish-Jewish lawyer named Raphael
>   Lemkin, who himself defined the term as reflecting "a coordinated plan
>   of different actions aiming at the destruction of essential
>   foundations of the life of national groups, with the aim of
>   annihilating the groups themselves."[[100]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Yazidis_by_ISIL#cite_note-100)

Comment: This answer could use a little bit more explanation., so that more readers can understand the point being made.